# Microsoft Surface Pro 2, dual booting Ubuntu Secure Remix 13.04 does not work, Live USB

Tags: 13.04, system-installation, live-usb, nomodeset, surface

If I boot from the Live USB and just select 'Try Ubuntu without Installing' it hangs on a black screen. If I go into edit options and type in 'only-ubiquity nomodeset' and remove 'quiet splash' and boot, it works. However I NEED unity, because I need to make sure if Grub is fixed (with the boot repair tool). And I can't open terminal either in this mode to just do that. PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: Don't the virtual terminals exist?  Try Ctrl-Alt-F2  to switch to one.  If that doesn't work, try just Alt-F2.  Get back to the X window screen with Alt-F7 if necessary.

Comment: yes, it sends me to:
ubuntu@ubuntu:^$:
Okay after I install ubuntu how would I just go and find the secure remix with this. I'm still new to this sorry.

Comment: When I ls, it doesn't show anything other than Desktop, and when I cd to that it just shows two options:
examples.desktop and ubiquity.desktop <-- this is an executable

Comment: I've never heard of Secure Remix, but I have found this tutorial on how to install Ubuntu on Surface Pro (1), is it any help? http://www.geek.com/microsoft/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-surface-pro-1539262/